# Can I move the android:duration of an animation-list item to attrs.xml?

Tags: android, android-animation

Is it possible to have an animation like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pr_l_b01"
        android:duration="@dont-know-what/animation_frame_duration"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pr_l_b02"
        android:duration="@dont-know-what/animation_frame_duration"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pr_l_b03"
        android:duration="@dont-know-what/animation_frame_duration"/>

</animation-list>
```

and in **attrs.xml**:

```
<dont-know-what name="animation_frame_duration"/></dont-know-what>
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [duration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3aduration) attribute in android developers.

> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

Insert your duration value in values.xml like this:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="duration">700</integer>
</resources>
```

And use it like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/pr_l_b01"
        android:duration="@integer/duration"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Answers with concrete examples are always better! Good job!